# Different content in Footer from the ItemTemplate result

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can the DataList `FooterTemplate` have an altogether different query result in contrast to what we are using in ItemTemplate results, on data binding?

For eg:

```
<ItemTemplate>
<tr>
<td>BookID: </td>
<td><%#Eval("bookid")%</td>
</tr>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
<tr>
<td>Last purchase: </td>
<td><%#Eval("")% //don't have a the result in the ItemTemplate queried DataSource result. Need to do a separate query for this and enter the columnID here</td>
</tr>
</FooterTemplate>
```

I need run a different query to get the result in footer. For this, the the same result should also be in the DataSource for the DataList, so that I can specify it using an ID.

Any suggestions for this or should I use an altogether different control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of binding it design time, use ItemDataBound event as below

```
if( e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Footer )
{    Label myLabel = ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("mylabelid"));
    mylabel.Text="datafrom db";
}
```

Comment: But the binding of the the ItemTempate can remain as it is, right? Adn we are not looking at any formatting options here that we have at desgin time?

Comment: let itemtemplate bindings remain there. You can format the content in the item databound before assign it to the control.